# Calculating the row max and index of an array

Tags: arrays, r, max, apply, min

Suppose I have an array of dimension (i,j,k) and I want to loop through the dimension k and calculate for each matrix(i,j) the row max and the row indices. How could I avoid a double apply function. The problem of the double apply is that it is slow because it does not handle efficient the creation of the result matrices, for example:

```
    Array <- rnorm(10000000)
dim(Array) <- c(1, 10000000,1)
system.time(apply(Array, 3, function(x)apply(x,1,function(y)c(min(y), max(y), which.min(y), which.max(y))))) 
system.time(apply(Array, 3, rowRanges))
system.time(apply(Array, 3, function(y)c(min(y), max(y), which.min(y), which.max(y))))
```

How could I avoid the double apply function, and is it possible to calculate the position of the min and max in a more efficient way? In this example the array is an vector but in real life it is a real array

The example was more to prove that the apply function causes overhead. The range function only calculates the min and the max and not the indices. Here the real example that I want to optimise(Notice that the first indices 10 in the example is in reallife around 1500 but then the array is around 16 gb)

```
Array <- rnorm(35000*36*10)
dim(Array) <- c(10, 35000,36)
test1 <- apply(Array, 3, function(x)apply(x,1,function(y)c(min(y), max(y), which.min(y), which.max(y))))
dim(test1) <- c(4, 10,36)
test2 <- apply(Array, 3, rowRanges)
dim(test2) <- c(10,2,36)
test2 <- aperm(test2, c(2,1,3))
sum(!test2 == test1[1:2,,])
```

Comment: Your array is just a vector. Can't you just treat it as one? Or in real life you have something else?

Comment: I'm sorry in real life it is just a real array not a vector:)

Comment: @TobiasDekker try to provide an example close to what you're dealing with in real life (at least the dimensions).

Comment: Can you provide a small example array and the expected output? Your three approaches seem to return different results.

Comment: I hope this makes more sense for you both

Comment: You could calculate the `which.min` and `which.max` of each row with `max.col(x, "first")` and `max.col(-x, "first")` respectively but, I guess, that would result in small speed gains. You could, also, organize your 3D "array" in a 2D "matrix" with `t(array(aperm(Array, c(2, 1, 3)), c(dim(x)[2], prod(dim(Array)[c(1, 3)]))))` and use the `max.col`s without looping over the third dimension (and, then somehow, split the results over the 3rd dimension) but that might give you memory problems (aside the fact, that still wouldn't be very efficient). You might need to consider moving to C code.